# WaitForSelectorAsync can't find element with id

Tags: c#, html, puppeteer, ui-automation

I have a puppeteersharp application. The application visits the google maps site. The google page opens up a Cookie Pop-up
[image]

I am trying to click on the "Ich stimme zu" (I agree) Button.
[image]

The Button has the id "introAgreeButton". But the `await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#introAgreeButton");` cannot find it times out with the error:

```
PuppeteerSharp.WaitTaskTimeoutException: 'waiting for selector '#introAgreeButton' failed: timeout 30000 ms exceeded'
```

**Why is the Method "WaitForSelectorAsync()" not finding the id even though it's present in the html**?

I looked at other solutions like suggesting `WaitForNavigationAsync()` but it still didn't work.

Here's my whole code, it's pretty straight forward:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PuppeteerSharp;

namespace GoogleMapsChecker
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // launch browser and save in variable
            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,
                ExecutablePath =
                    @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" // get path to chrome executable
            });

            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            await page.GoToAsync("https://www.google.ch/maps/@47.4754032,9.0517207,14z");
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#introAgreeButton");
            await page.ClickAsync("#introAgreeButton");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We are suddenly experiencing the same behavior, without changing anything to the code.